# How to get the iTunes pricing matrices in 2021?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes, price, itunes-store

It seems the button to download the whole pricing matrix is gone in App Store Connect now, **not only that**, but now the website limits the amount of countries you can see...

*[https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/pricingmatrix/{Your_App_Id}](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/pricingmatrix/%7BYour_App_Id%7D)*

[image: App Store]

For the pricing matrix for *Consumable* In-App products, the button is there, but does **nothing**...
[https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/{Your_App_Id}/pricingMatrix/consumable/{Your_Product_Id}](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/%7BYour_App_Id%7D/pricingMatrix/consumable/%7BYour_Product_Id%7D)
[image: Consumables]

BUT For *recurring subscriptions*, the option to download the price tiers is there, and seems to work though...
*[https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/{Your_App_Id}/pricingMatrix/recurring/{Your_Product_Id}](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/%7BYour_App_Id%7D/pricingMatrix/recurring/%7BYour_Product_Id%7D)*

[image: Recurring subscriptions]

**What's the correct way to fetch the information in 2021, and being able to work alongside this platform at all?**

**Is it the [App Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi)? Doesn't seem to support price matrix for in-app products...**

**Is it the [Transporter app](https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/) and the iTMS command line tool? It seems you only get price tiers in there, not actual currency or amounts**

Answer (score 1):

> For the pricing matrix for Consumable In-App products, the button is
> there, but does nothing...
> [https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/{Your_App_Id}/pricingMatrix/consumable/{Your_Product_Id}](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/%7BYour_App_Id%7D/pricingMatrix/consumable/%7BYour_Product_Id%7D)

Entering "consumable/" in the above URL will bring up a page with a download link for pricing matrices.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.